# JavaScript syntax: const pureComponentPrototype = (PureComponent.prototype = new ComponentDummy());

Tags: javascript, reactjs, syntax

I've been looking into code inside Facebook's react project to learn more about JavaScript. In particular, I saw syntax that looks like this

```
const pureComponentPrototype = (PureComponent.prototype = new ComponentDummy());
```

I've never encountered code like this before. What does it mean when `PureComponent.prototype = new ComponentDummy()` is wrapped inside parenthesis?

What is the name for this type of syntax? Thanks in advance.

Comment: The parenthesis is just for readability. all you are doing is a = b = 5;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parenthesis are just for readability. all you are doing is

```
a = b = 5;
```

Actually the assignment operator returns the left side value.

e.g. : `function test() { let b; return b = 5; } test(); // 5`

So that should be it. Note that if we don't declare 'b' variable with let/var/const it will become a global variable. But thats one different discussion.

Comment: Note that `(function () { const a = b = 5; })()` will create a **global** `b` variable!

Comment: umm... here I thought of ignoring global or not global thing coz thats not the point of question as it seems

Comment: I'm just anticipating the next question Alex Wang might post, before they post it :)

Comment: Lol, you are right. I am gonna edit my answer to explain more ;)

Comment: Interesting. Does that mean I can do something like `(function() { const a = let b = 5; }) ()` ?

Comment: All you have to do is declare the variable b before hand. So you should write (function() { let b; const a = b = 5; }) ()

Comment: This is because assignment operator expects no scope identifier on right hand side. Pardon me for using the word scope identifier but I am not sure of what it is called. :)